# Windows Server Auditing Capabilities

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing, security

I was curious if it were possible to audit a file share on windows server 2012 for a copy. How can one differentiate a copied file rather than a read file based on the events they send to the event log? Is there a certain pattern a copied file takes in terms of reading and writing?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the share level, no.  This is due to shares do not have system acl's.  But you can enable auditing on the file system level for Write access to the shared folder.  Refer to the following help text for the Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > Object Access:

---

File System

This policy setting allows you to audit user attempts to access file system objects. A security audit event is generated only for objects that have system access control lists (SACL) specified, and only if the type of access requested, such as Write, Read, or Modify and the account making the request match the settings in the SACL. For more information about enabling object access auditing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=122083.

If you configure this policy setting, an audit event is generated each time an account accesses a file system object with a matching SACL. Success audits record successful attempts and Failure audits record unsuccessful attempts.
If you do not configure this policy setting, no audit event is generated when an account accesses a file system object with a matching SACL.

Note: You can set a SACL on a file system object using the Security tab in that object's Properties dialog box.

Volume: Depends on how the file system SACLs are configured.

Comment: Right. So there is no difference - on the file share or file system level - between opening a file and copying it from the server to your computer. Because "read, write, modify" are quite vague.

Comment: No, the server auditing does not have the granularity to distinguish if a read is a file being copied to another computer.